# Some Android phones add two identical photos to the gallery after launching the camera app and getting the result

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

My app starts the camera app like this:

```
localImageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                   MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                   new ContentValues());

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                      .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, localImageUri);

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, RETURN_FROM_CAMERA);
```

The camera app starts, I take a photo, confirm the photo, and I am returned to my app as expected.  On some phones, such as the Samsung Sidekick, there are always two identical photos in the camera's gallery after this workflow.  On other phones, this works perfectly without leaving duplicate photos in the gallery.

Is there a way to change this code to avoid the duplicate photos on those phones?